# retrieving specific data from json array using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Hi guys need a little help here since I am a begiiner in javascript Please note that my question might be a duplicate to you all but I need a little enlightenment here, anyway I need to get to display the data I need from a JSON array lets say  I have 3 array

```
var = countrysites[ "Denmark"],["United States"],["France"]
```

if I click the marker for Denmark using basic javascript Onclick it would display the data for Denmark only not calling all data of USA and France. Here is my javascript code

```
function displayData(){
for (var i = 0; i < countrysites.length; i++) {
    if (countrysites[i].country_name === id) {
      countrysites[i].country_name = country_name;

    }
  }
}
```

and my div has an id of 'sitemark' and has onclick of displayData

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to properly show your data structure. Your code seems to be using an array of objects, not JSON ([JSON is a textual format](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)), and the code shown seems to be modifying the data, not displaying anything. It would help to show that code in context - from the use of `return` presumably it is in a function, so show the function and how you call it.

Comment: please share the json reponse

Comment: @nnnnnn there you go I have edited my codes

Comment: @brk the result would be 0: 'country_name': 'Denmark',
                                         1: 'country_name': 'France,
                                         2: 'country_name': 'USA'

well in reality all i want to display is Denmark only if I click in denmark and display France if I click France

Comment: Are you sure your data isn't this?: `var countrysites = [ "Denmark", "United States", "France"];` this declares am array with 3 strings. `var countrysites["Denmark"],["United States"],["France"]` is syntactically wrong. And makes no sense to have 3 separate arrays when one is all you actually need.

Comment: No-one can answer your question as you haven't clearly stated what your data structure is. This => `var = countrysites[ "Denmark"],["United States"],["France"]` makes no sense, particularly when your code in the next section talks about `country_name` which would be the property of an _object_. Maybe add the JSON you're receiving to your question.

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to be going through a multi-dimensional array you'd have to use two for loops like so

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    if(whatever you're looking for) {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: actually I've used for loops but the result would be the same it will display the name of other countries as well in one click

Answer (score -1):

I've taken some liberties in answering this because I'm still not sure what your data-structure looks like, but hopefully this will help.

Here's the data you're receiving as JSON which you then parse. It's array of objects each of which contains `country_name` and `info` properties.

```
const countryInfo = [
  { country_name: 'Denmark', info: 'This is Denmark' },
  { country_name: 'England', info: 'This is England' },
  { country_name: 'Japan', info: 'This is Japan' }
];
```

For the purposes of this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r81kLf0b/7/)** we grab the `body` element, and then grab an array of *just* the country names from the data.

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const names = countryInfo.map(obj => obj.country_name);
```

We build some markers with that array data and add them to the `body` element. Note the data attribute `data-name`. We store a copy of the country name here.

```
names.forEach(name => {
  const html = `<div class="sitemark" data-name="${name}">${name}</div>`;
  body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
});
```

We grab the `info` element. This is where we add the country information.

```
const info = document.querySelector('#info');
```

We grab the markers and add event listeners to them. When one is clicked, call the `displayData` function.

```
const sitemarks = document.querySelectorAll('.sitemark');
sitemarks.forEach(marker => {
  marker.addEventListener('click', displayData, false);
});
```

To get the countryinfo we perform a `find` operation on the `countryInfo` array that pulls out the first object instance where the country name is the same as the name in the `data-name` attribute on the element, and then take the `info` value from that object. Then we add that text to the `info` element.

```
function displayData() {
  const text = countryInfo.find(obj => obj.country_name === this.dataset.name).info;
  info.innerHTML = text;
}
```